# How to join rows in the same table by a shared column id with a where clause?

Tags: sql, select, join, where-clause, rows

I'm trying to write a SQL query that looks at a single MySQL DB table (`exp_playa_relationships`) which stores relationship data of CMS' posts and which data structure looks like this:

```
rel_id  |  parent_entry_id  |  parent_field_id  |  child_entry_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
55      |  3                |  2                |  1
56      |  3                |  2                |  4
58      |  1                |  2                |  4
59      |  8                |  4                |  2
60      |  8                |  5                |  1
63      |  4                |  2                |  3
64      |  9                |  4                |  6
65      |  9                |  5                |  3
```

`rel_id` is unique, other columns are not.

I would like to generate the following out of the data above:

```
event_data_id  |  user_id  |  event_id
--------------------------------------
8              |  1        |  2
9              |  3        |  6
```

The `parent_field_id` value itself is discarded in the final output but is needed to figure out if the row's `child_entry_id` signifies a `user_id` or `event_id`.

`parent_entry_id` is the `event_data_id`.

So in plain english I would like to:

1. Filter rows that have a `parent_field_id` value of either `4` or `5`
2. Out of those rows, I want to join all those that share the same `parent_entry_id`.
3. Return the `parent_entry_id` as `event_data_id`.
4. Return the `child_entry_id` as a `user_id` if `parent_field_id` of the same row is `5`.
5. Return the `child_entry_id` as a `event_id` if `parent_field_id` of the same row is `4`.

My current SQL query (not working) is this:

```
SELECT
    t1.`parent_entry_id` AS event_data_id,
    t1.`child_entry_id` AS user_id,
    t1.`child_entry_id` AS event_id

FROM `exp_playa_relationships` AS t1
INNER JOIN `exp_playa_relationships` AS t2
ON t1.`parent_entry_id` = t2.`parent_entry_id`
WHERE t1.`parent_field_id` = 4 OR t1.`parent_field_id` = 5
```

What I cannot figure out specifically is how to avoid creating duplicates on the `parent_entry_id` (SQL creates 2 new rows per row) and how to return `child_entry_id` as either `user_id` or `event_id` based on the `parent_field_id` value.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *sooo* close:

```
SELECT t1.`parent_entry_id` AS event_data_id,
       t1.`child_entry_id` AS user_id,
       t2.`child_entry_id` AS event_id
FROM `exp_playa_relationships` AS t1
INNER JOIN `exp_playa_relationships` AS t2
        ON t2.`parent_entry_id` = t1.`parent_entry_id`
           AND t2.`parent_field_id` = 4
WHERE  t1.`parent_field_id` = 5
```

Specifically, you're having to tell it which row-set to pull the relevant data from.

By the way, your current database design will cause you more of these types of headaches... I'd recommend pulling the information out into 'result' tables (unless that's what this is for?).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Everything works great. And I think I understand what's going on… to recap: we're reducing the subset of t1 to only those that have `parent_field_id` of `5` to avoid duplicates, then in the `INNER JOIN` we're checking that the `parent_field_id` is matching that of t1 and that we've got a matching `event_id` data based on the row's `parent_field_id` of `4`. Is that right?

Comment: Oh and as for the DB design… it's the design of the CMS (ExpressionEngine) and it's add-ons so there is little I can do to change that myself. Having said that, what I'm doing with this query is in fact building a result table of users attending a certain event so hopefully this will be the only case where I even need to go into these types of manual SQL queries and the rest will be handled natively by the CMS.